# How to improve performance of this stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance, execution-time

Below is the stored procedure's dynamic query result which is fetching records from a view and other tables using join as shown below. It is fetching only 5 rows, but taking 13 seconds to execute. I need to reduce execution time.

How can I achieve that? I have already used execution plan no index is missing in the table used in this query. Suggest any other way. I also analyzed that view is taking much time to execute, is there any way to improve view performance as well?

```
DECLARE @MonthId int

SELECT TOP 1 
    @MonthId = Month_Id 
FROM
    CVBAT_Mart.dbo.Fact_AE_CurrentMonth WITH (NOLOCK)

SELECT    
    Site_Churn_Cd    
    ,SUM(FAE.Site_Count) AS Site_Count    
    ,SUM(FAE.Account_Count) AS Account_Count        
    ,FORMAT(SUM(TY_DailyVolume),'0,0,') as TY_ADV    
    ,FORMAT(SUM(LY_DailyVolume),'0,0') as LY_ADV    
    ,Site_Churn_Cd_color =    
              CASE WHEN Site_Churn_Cd = 'D' THEN 'f8bd19'    
                   WHEN Site_Churn_Cd = 'G' THEN '33ccff'    
                   WHEN Site_Churn_Cd = 'L' THEN 'ccff66'    
                   WHEN Site_Churn_Cd = 'N' THEN 'ffcccc'    
                   WHEN Site_Churn_Cd = 'U' THEN 'c0c0c0'    
                   ELSE Site_Churn_Cd 
              END
FROM 
    CVBAT_Mart.dbo.vFact_AE_Service_Category_TT FAE WITH (NOLOCK)     
INNER JOIN 
    common_ESTAT.dbo.SR_Hierarchy_ESTAT_Promoted_Monthly ESTAT WITH (NOLOCK) ON FAE.Enprs_Employee_Id = ESTAT.SR_Level_1_ID 
WHERE 
    c_Excluded_Flag = 'N'    
    AND c_Site_Primary_AE = '1'    
    AND FAE.Month_Id = @MonthId      
    AND Customer_Shipment_Role_Cd = '03'    
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1         
                FROM CVBAT_Mart.dbo.DIM_Geography DG WITH (NOLOCK)    
                WHERE Organization_Active_Ind = 1    
                  AND DG.Region_Num = ESTAT.SR_Level_1_Region_Num    
                  AND DG.District_Num = ESTAT.SR_Level_1_District_Num)
  GROUP BY    
      Site_Churn_Cd
```

Comment: I think it come with your `Exists` clause

Comment: Can you include said query plan, as well as the schema of the relevant objects?

Comment: Table definitions, indexes, and query plan.

Comment: I hope you know all the unwanted effects that using NOLOCK can cause.

Answer (score 1):

Without an execution plan and/or additional schema data there isn't much to go on. EXISTS can cause performance concerns and should be replaceable with a JOIN condition. I don't think this will solve your problem but try it anyways.

When posting queries like this, please make sure you alias all fields. The aliases help to imply some schema information, though it is not nearly as good as actual schema data.

```
DECLARE @MonthId INT
SELECT  TOP 1
        @MonthId = Month_Id
FROM    CVBAT_Mart.dbo.Fact_AE_CurrentMonth WITH (NOLOCK)

SELECT  Site_Churn_Cd,
        SUM( FAE.Site_Count ) AS Site_Count,
        SUM( FAE.Account_Count ) AS Account_Count,
        FORMAT( SUM( TY_DailyVolume ), '0,0,' ) AS TY_ADV,
        FORMAT( SUM( LY_DailyVolume ), '0,0' ) AS LY_ADV,
        Site_Churn_Cd_color = CASE
                                  WHEN Site_Churn_Cd = 'D' THEN 'f8bd19'
                                  WHEN Site_Churn_Cd = 'G' THEN '33ccff'
                                  WHEN Site_Churn_Cd = 'L' THEN 'ccff66'
                                  WHEN Site_Churn_Cd = 'N' THEN 'ffcccc'
                                  WHEN Site_Churn_Cd = 'U' THEN 'c0c0c0'
                                  ELSE Site_Churn_Cd
                              END
FROM    CVBAT_Mart.dbo.vFact_AE_Service_Category_TT AS FAE WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN    common_ESTAT.dbo.SR_Hierarchy_ESTAT_Promoted_Monthly AS ESTAT WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON  ESTAT.SR_Level_1_ID = FAE.Enprs_Employee_Id
JOIN    CVBAT_Mart.dbo.DIM_Geography AS DG WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON  DG.Organization_Active_Ind = 1
    AND DG.Region_Num = ESTAT.SR_Level_1_Region_Num
    AND DG.District_Num = ESTAT.SR_Level_1_District_Num
WHERE   c_Excluded_Flag = 'N'
    AND c_Site_Primary_AE = '1'
    AND Customer_Shipment_Role_Cd = '03'
    AND FAE.Month_Id = @MonthId
GROUP BY Site_Churn_Cd
```

Comment: I upvote because i think your answer is good but i did not try

Comment: If you are not returning any data from a table, using `EXISTS` operator in most cases out performs `INNER JOIN`. I strongly disagree with your comment about "EXISTS can cause performance concerns", I'm sorry.

Comment: @Chris I tried the way, query you modified here it is now taking 17 sec, i mean it is taking more time , before it was taking 13 sec , is there any other way

Comment: there is a view and I tried fetching data from view explicitly, and I realized view is taking more time. In the view only Union is used between two select query. Is there any way to improve performance of view. Also I executed view with estimated query plan I could not get any result like missing view.

Comment: @Ayu, there are a lot of ways to improve the performance of views, but without the code there are very few that I could suggest. I can't offer much advice beyond what I've done without more data on schema or the structure of the view.

Comment: @Chris View is having two select statement and union in between.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the query returns only 5 rows, but note that the query is an aggregation of rows spanning two tables. The performance of the query will be proportional to the number of rows before aggregation is applied. You can reason with the time taken based on that rather than using the final aggregated row count.

Let's for the moment assume that even before aggregation the number of rows is reasonable. In that case, you would need to ensure you have the right set of indexes to facilitate the WHERE conditions, the JOIN and the EXISTS. This is where looking at the execution plan for your query would guide you.

You can even break down the query into each stage check performance at each stage. I notice that the first table involved in the query is actually a View, going by the naming. It is possible that the view is another set of table joins.

Overall, your best bet would be build up the query in steps and check for any optimizations with respect to indexes at each step. Being able to read and understand the query execution plan is essential to get the best result.

Comment: you are right there is a view and I tried fetching data from view explicitly, and I realized view is taking more time. In the view only Union is used between two select query. Is there any way to improve performance of view. Also I executed view with estimated query plan I could not get any result like missing view.